# Location capture error - Delay

Tags: android

When I start the application, I'll check if the location data is active. Otherwise, send a user to a GPS / Local setup screen.

Problem:

When GPS has been disabled for some time and enabled, an error occurs in the application. But if you wait a few seconds, it will work correctly. There is a kind of delay.

What could be wrong with my Location Checks?

How could I improve this?

Code where I check:

```
Code OnCreate:

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

        getLocationPermission();

        if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {

            //Avisar que nao tem GPS acionado
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Gps is not active....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();

        } else {

            getDeviceLocation();

}
```

Functions:

```
private void getDeviceLocation() {
        /*
         * Get the best and most recent location of the device, which may be null in rare
         * cases when a location is not available.
         */
        try {

            if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
                Task<Location> locationResult = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            mLastKnownLocation = task.getResult();

                            /*FireStore*/
                            Map<String, Object> geoUser = new HashMap<>();
                            geoUser.put("Coordenadas", new GeoPoint(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()));
                            geoUser.put("Coordenadas_timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

                            Task<Void> coordenadasUser = db.collection("Usuarios").document(mCurrentUser.getUid())
                                    .update(geoUser).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                            //OK

                                        }
                                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                                            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });


                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        } catch (SecurityException e)  {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        }
}


private void getLocationPermission() {
        /*
         * Request location permission, so that we can get the location of the
         * device. The result of the permission request is handled by a callback,
         * onRequestPermissionsResult.
         */
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the result of the request for location permissions.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Thanks !!

Comment: nothing is wrong with the current problem you are facing. because when you turn on GPS of your device it took 1500ms to 2000ms to get turn on your hardware functionality then after 1500ms to 2000ms you will get location updates, i will suggest you to get location of user in handler i.e with delay.

Comment: How could I have solved this? @LakshayJuneja

Comment: @ TiagoIB as i have already mentioned in my comment try to getDeviceLocation() in Handler with delay.

Comment: You say create a Delayed Handler to later call the: getDeviceLocation() ? @LakshayJuneja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you, i have used broadcast receiver

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Location location;

    private BroadcastReceiver locationSettingReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (isLocationEnabled(MainActivity.this) && location == null) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getDeviceLocation();
            }
        }, 1500);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        registerReceiver(locationSettingReceiver, new IntentFilter(android.location.LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (locationSettingReceiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(locationSettingReceiver);
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

     private boolean isLocationEnabled(Context context) {
        android.location.LocationManager locationManager = (android.location.LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(android.location.LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay. I'll test and I'll answer later! @LakshayJuneja